# htaccess RewriteRule match special characters in URL-path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with the correct `RewriteRule`.

Need URL with JSON string at the end:

```
http://hns/log/r/%7B"start":%5B55.70980850022872,37.505353142456336%5D,"end":%5B55.70980850022872,37.77039830847196%5D,"points":%5B%5B55.67529029803404,37.62070958776883%5D%5D,"method":"1","optimization":"1","center":%5B55.731512133266634,37.71615331335479%5D,"zoom":10%7D
```

redirect to

```
http://hns/log/r/index.html
```

without changing URL in the browser.

`.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /log/r/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ./index.html?catalog=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9?;:,{}\"]+)$ ./index.html [L]
```

It works well with URLs like: `http://hns/log/r/,132a`.
But doesn't work with URLs like: `http://hns/log/r/,132a:` or with quote symbol (`"`) or like JSON string.

How to redirect such URL correctly?

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? I assume it must be in `/logist/route/.htaccess`? Is `/log/r/` your shorthand for `/logist/route/`? Or a completely different URL-path?

Comment: Sorry, redirection should be to `http://hns/log/r/index.html`. .htaccess file is at  `http://hns/log/r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are perhaps testing this on a Windows machine? On Windows OS, the colon (`:`) and quote (`"`) characters are not permitted filename characters. So when Apache tries to map the request to a filesystem path (which it will do if `/log/r` is a filesystem directory) you'll get an error (which is likely to result in Apache serving a 403 Forbidden), regardless of your mod_rewrite regex, which already contains these characters.

Other forbidden filename characters on Windows: `\`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`.

If you need this to work on Windows then you'll need to change your URL structure. eg. Use PATH_INFO or a query string.

However, your existing code should already work on a Linux machine for URLs of the form `http://hns/log/r/,132a:` (containing a colon) or with quote (`"`) characters.

> `http://hns/log/r/%7B"start":%5B55.70980850022872,37.505353142456336%5D,"end":%5B55.70980850022872,37.77039830847196%5D,"points":%5B%5B55.67529029803404,37.62070958776883%5D%5D,"method":"1","optimization":"1","center":%5B55.731512133266634,37.71615331335479%5D,"zoom":10%7D`

However, the code posted will not work for JSON strings of the form given above because you have not included all the necessary characters. You are missing `[`, `]` and `.` (dot/period). Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the %-decoded URL-path. So, this should be written like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9?;:,{}"\[\].]+)$ index.php [L]
```

Note also I have removed the `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. Prefixing with `./` is not required (and not strictly correct). If prefixed with `./` mod_rewrite simply sees the *substitution* as relative (ie. it doesn't start with a slash or scheme+hostname) and will simply apply the directory-prefix. In this case, the resulting URL-path will be `/log/r/./index.php` - however, this still resolves correctly by the OS and "works".